# How to organize Json data got from bls.gov

Tags: python, json, pandas

The homework requests that we should use the sample codes to get data from BLS and organize them in the same dataset. 
But I tried many ways but still failed to organize them by using dataframe. Can anyone help?

The sample codes is similar from https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_python.htm
Based on the SeriesID definitions, the homework requests retrieve the following data:

Seasonally adjusted (Seasonal Adjustment code) Average weekly earnings of all employees (Data type code) of Manufacturing, financial activities and Professional and business services (Super Sector Code) from Year 1980 to 2018 from this section.

Attention: the maximum number of queries for this website is 25 times.

So I wrote as below:

```
import requests
import json
import prettytable
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid": ['CUUR0000SA0','CUUR0000SA0 ',"startyear":"2010", "endyear":"2018"})
p = requests.post('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/', 
data=data, headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(p.text)

for series in json_data['Results']['series']:
    x=prettytable.PrettyTable(["series id","year","period","value","footnotes"])
    seriesId = series['seriesID']
    for item in series['data']:
        year = item['year']
        period = item['period']
        value = item['value']
     footnotes=""
        for footnote in item['footnotes']:
           if footnote:
              footnotes = footnotes + footnote['text'] + ','
        #if 'M01' <= period <= 'M12':
         #   x.add_row([seriesId,year,period,value,footnotes[0:-1]])
```

And I extracted the data as follows:

```
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  series id  | year | period |  value  | footnotes |
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M12   | 134.207 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M11   | 135.107 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M10   | 135.891 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M09   | 136.211 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M08   | 136.127 |           |



+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  series id  | year | period |  value  | footnotes |
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M12   | 234.812 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M11   | 236.151 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M10   | 237.433 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M09   | 238.031 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M08   | 237.852 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M07   | 238.250 |           |
```

Can anyone tell me how to use pandas dataframe to combine them into a dataset?

Comment: Could you post some specific JSON data? Also, `Below is the codes I write to organize, but failed` -- specifically what was the failure?

Comment: The JSON data is exactly I scraped from the website by using the codes above. The jsoin_data. Then I  used for loop to store. I don't know how to output the data in organized way. The failure is that there is no data output.

Comment: Can you post the specific JSON data, or a self-contained example (edit it into your question)? I tried running the code and got a "maximum API calls exceeded" error message.

Comment: This is the same for me. But it works for me this morning. Maybe I also tried too many times. From the website, it is said that the maximum queries is 25 times per day.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Depending on where exactly your problems are, it may be completely unnecessary to query that API, you can as well replace this query with hardcoded values for example purposes. Then, it's still not clear what exactly your problem is. The code you wrote in the second snippet is obviously useless, because it has messed up indentation. Make sure anyone can just grab the code and feed it to Python as is. As new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].