# How to find the id which has multiple matchings from Kaggle Football data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In the homework, we are asked to find the id which has multiple matchings. Just like in database, there is one to many relationships.

I could only specify that both ids do not match. Since the distinct count number differs.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
player_att = pd.read_csv('Player_Attributes.csv',sep = ',') 
player_att.head()

player_att.player_fifa_api_id.nunique()  
player_att.player_api_id.nunique()
```

For the above codes, the results are 11062, 11060. That is to say the two id numbers do not match. But how to find the one with multiple fifa_api_id?

Comment: can you create a sample dataframe? and expected output? refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
player_att.groupby('player_fifa_api_id').player_api_id.count()
```

Basically, `groupby` will gather all rows with the same `player_fifa_api_id` together, and `count` returns the number (count) of each group.

After this, you have a series named `player_api_id` and indexed by `player_fifa_api_id`. If you want to players with more than one `player_api_id`, then you look at the series where the value is larger than 1.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit? I don't understand.

Comment: But why the two don't match?

Comment: OK. Got you! If you have time, could you look at other question from my homework? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432851/how-to-organize-json-data-got-from-bls-gov